# Which power combiner should I use?

Tags: pcb, analog, filter, microwave

I have two microwave signals (0.2 and 2.3 GHz) and I have to join these signals in a common channel (microstrip TXline).

I've decided to use two BP filters and a power combiner hybrid.

I've already designed the filters, but I don't know which power combiners' (like Wilkinson, Rat-race hybrid, etc.) bandwidth is big enough for them.

Which type of structure would be ideal?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the answer directly, but if the signal power levels aren't too high, I'd be tempted to just try to design this with discrete components:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I don't promise it will be easy to tune the component values in the real world to get the performance you want.